# I am not getting the desired output from the code, it seems something is wrong with the while loop

Tags: c++, function, class

1) At the start of the game the user is given the choice to choose a type of player (1, 2, 3)

2) Each type of player starts with below attributes -

3) Player 1 - max health = 50, damage = 10, heal = 20

4) Player 2 - max health = 75, damage = 25, heal = 10

5) Player 3 - max health = 100, damage = 75, heal = 20

6) A player can be healed to a max health only (*ignore this as I haven't  coded it yet*)

7) After a player is spawned, the game lets the player take damage or get healed as below

8) "Press D (to take damage) or H (to heal) the player"

9) pressing D or H can be repeated infinite number of times till player's health drops below 0

10) When player health is 0 or below 0 the game is over!

11) Now the user is presented with the below choice -

12) Press S to start the game again

13) Press E to end the program

14) If the user presses "S", the entire game starts again and the user can now create a new player of any 
type (1, 2, 3)

15) If the user presses "E", the entire program ends!

**THE PROBLEM:** [image: [This Image shows the output]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkZQi.png) When the condition for exiting while loop is met it does exit from the while loop but on pressing any other number to spawn a player the "damage" and "heal" don't work The output is blank

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int input;
char input1;
bool gameOver;

class player
{
    public:void p(int Health,int Damage,int Heal)
    {
        do
        {
          cout << "Player Health is" << Health;
          cin >> input1;

          switch(input1)
              {
                  case 'd':
                      Health -= Damage;
                      break;
                  case 'h':
                      Health += Heal;
                      break;
              }

           if(Health == 0 || input1 == 's')
           {
                gameOver = true;
           }

        } while (gameOver == false);
    }
}p1;

int main()
{

    do{
        //system("cls");
        cin >> input;

        if(input == 1)
        {
            p1.p(50,10,20);
        }
        if(input == 2)
        {
            player p2;
            p2.p(75,25,10);
        }
        if(input == 3)
        {
            player p2;
            p2.p(100,75,20);
        }



    } while (input != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `gameOver` does not get reset to false when you start the next player game loop.
Try something like this:

```
void p(int Health, int Damage, int Heal)
{
  gameOver = false;
  do
  {
    // game logic...
  } while (gameOver == false)
}
```